# Django. How to find error details on Heroku project

Tags: django, heroku

I have a Django app deployed on Heroku. It has been there for several months now. It is a small forum. Today, someone ran across a weird error and I'm wondering how can I find the details of that error.

I use Papertrail and all I get about the error is:

```
 Jun 19 09:26:31 whispering-castle-2137 heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/temas/inicio/" host=*** request_id=78685698-6fd7-4311-9b0b-04721b1064a4 fwd="181.72.204.178" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=85ms status=500 bytes=987
```

This doesn't help at all.

I cannot simulate the error locally, what can I do?

Comment: Well, it seems you're not logging the error. Papertrail picks up everything on `stdout` and `stderr`, so your error's not going there.

Comment: How con I go there?, I'm not good at using Papertrail.

Comment: `heroku logs` not working ?

Comment: Go in to your application code then add `print` (or similar logging function) statements where an error might occur.

Comment: That is messing up with the code. I can do that, but it wont help me cause error already happened, and it happens in a strange way. I don't know what part of the code is failing-I would like to know that. I was hoping Papertrail keeps that somewhere.

Comment: @itzmeontv `heroku logs` gives me the same line. Or is there a way to extend the details?